# Adding class on ng-click

Tags: css, angularjs

I'm trying to use the arguments of an ng-click to add a class to the same element, but so far no luck.

What I'm doing wrong? 
Basically what I want to do is to add a certain class to the element when clicked. Right now, on ng-click, i'm declaring answer="yes".

Here's my code:

```
<div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2" ng-switch on="answer">

    <div class="row question">Do you like to travel?</div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <a class="btn col-md-12" ng-click="answer='yes'" ng-class="answer='yes' : 'active'" >Yes</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">            
          <a class="btn col-md-12" ng-click="answer='no'">No</a>
        </div>  
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax would be:

```
ng-class="{'active' : answer == 'yes'}"
```